# Why would the same exact Firebase Function take 10x as long to run using a schedule/onRun trigger than a HTTP onRequest trigger?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a 2 identical Firebase functions that batch write data to Firestore. One is wrapped in a scheduled/onRun trigger, and the other is a HTTP onRequest trigger.

Both functions work fine and throw no errors.

They have the same amount of memory and timeout as well.

When invoking the http trigger, the function runs through and completes in about 30 seconds.

When invoking the scheduled onRun trigger, the function takes 5+ minutes to complete.

Is there something different about the runtimes that is not documented or something?

Edit: It works now - I made processMentions await totalMentions and return null.

processMentions does not have to return a promise, only a value because the actual scheduledPull/onRun function is returning the processMentions async function, which resolves the promise by returning a value.

Cheers for the help @dougstevenson

Triggers:

```
/**
 * Get manual mentions 
 */
exports.get = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const topic = 'topic'
  const query = 'queryString'
  processMentions(res, query, topic)
})

/**
 * Get schedule mentions 
 */
exports.scheduledPull = functions.pubsub.schedule('every day 1:00').onRun((context) => {
    const topic = 'topic'
    const query = 'queryString'
    return processMentions('sched', query, topic)
  })
```

Logic:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()
const db = admin.firestore()
const axios = require('axios')
const moment = require('moment')

// Globals
const auth = 'token'
const url = 'https://apiurl.com/'

async function totalMentions(nextPage, start, end, query) {
  try {
    let config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: auth,
        Accept: 'text/html',
      }
    }
    const response = await axios.get(url, config)
    const total = response.data.results.total
    const loops = Math.ceil(total / 500)
    return loops
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error 1', error)
  }
}

async function allMentions(nextPage, start, end, query) {
  try {
    let config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: auth,
        Accept: 'text/html',
      },
    }
    const response = await axios.get(url, config)
    return response
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error 2', error)
  }
}

async function saveData(response, end, topic) {
  try {
    let data = await response.data.results.clips
    let batch = db.batch()
    data.forEach((c) => {
      delete c.localTime
        let reff = db.collection(collection).doc(date).collection(collection).doc(c.id.toString())
        batch.set(reff, c)
    })
    let batches = await batch.commit()
    return batches
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error3 ', error)
  }
}

async function processMentions(res, query, topic) {
  try {
    totalMentions(1, start, end, query)
      .then(async (loops) => {
        let endbatch = 0
        for (let i = 1; i <= loops; i++) {
          await allMentions(i, start, end, query)
            .then(async (response) => {
              await saveData(response, end, topic)
              return ++endbatch
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.log('error 4 ' + err)
            })
          if (endbatch === loops) {
            if (res !== 'sched') {
              console.log('http trigger finished')
              return res.status(200).end()
            } else {
              return console.log('schedule finished')
            }
          }
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('error5 ' + err)
      })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error6 ' + error)
  }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, we don't know if you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I understand - I'll add some code. But if the functions are exactly the same there must be some difference that is not code related?

Comment: Well, those two types of triggers definitely don't work the same.  HTTP triggers send a response when the work is done, while everything else must return a promise that resolves when the work is done.  The documentation is fairly clear on this.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the pubsub trigger to work correctly, `processMentions` needs to return a promise that resovles when all of the async work is complete. Right now, it's returning nothing, which (since it's declared async) translates into a promise that's resolved immediately with no value.  Calling then/catch on a promise isn't doing what you expect - you need to return a promise chain from your async work.

I'm not sure why you have it declared async, without also using await inside of it to manage the promises much more easily.

Comment: Thank you much! It seems obvious now that the processMentions function isn't returning anything, 'doh. If this fixes the 5+ minute running time I will mark this as the accepted answer. Cheers